# User TimeZone sensitive push notifications in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating a Flutter app where I need to allow the user to receive notifications each day at a scheduled time that they set, and the notifications will honour the timezone where the device is.

The notifications will contain dynamic content, rather than static content like one might use to set a reminder. So, I'm assuming that I need to use push notifications and a server-side function to create the dynamic content. For example, using a Firebase Cloud Function and Firebase Cloud Messaging.

What I don't know is how I might get the user's device timezone and the scheduled time they configured for their daily notifications into the Cloud Function.

Is this possible at the time that the device registers with Firebase Cloud Messaging? Or do I need to store the schedule time and timezone in Firestore and somehow pull it from there?

Any other tips for system components that can facilitate this use case would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Luke

Answer (score 1):

OK, after doing some more research with Dr Google, I found two very good YouTube videos that look like they will do what I need:

1. https://youtu.be/D4wgrgb24o0
2. https://youtu.be/I0r10sk5fuI

Thank you to Tadas Petra.